# How can I find the one element in an NSArray greater than a certain value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, time

I'm at the beginning in iOS Development. I have an array like the following:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15:00]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20:05]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1:20]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3:40]];
```

I need a label to show which array object is the next one greater than my current time. For example, if my current time now is: 2:00, my label should show me just the next greater number, 3:40. Not numbers greater than this.

How can I identify this one greater element?

Comment: Please include your real code in your questions. This code is not just invalid, it doesn't really make sense -- 20:05 is not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

First off, why are you adding `NSNumbers` to your `NSArray`? These should be `NSDate` objects.

If you do that, you can use NSDate's compare method like this:

```
[date1 compare: date2];
```

In your case, if you want to show the time immediately after your current time, I'd do something like this:

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSUInteger smallestInterval = -1;
NSInteger smallestDateIndex = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++){
    if([currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[array objectAtIndex:i]] <= 0){
    continue;
    }

    if(smallestDateIndex == -1){
        smallestDateIndex = i;
        smallestInterval = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    } else if([currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[array objectAtIndex:i]] < smallestInterval){
    smallestInterval = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    smallestDateIndex = i;
    }
}

if(smallestDateIndex > -1){
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    myLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[array objectAtIndex:smallestDateIndex]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you write a little example, please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: He just gave you an example. Look at the documentation for `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I added an example, but really you should be researching these things yourself if you expect to get anywhere with iOS development. A good 70-80% of development time should be spent researching and planning out the best solution via documentation and searching.

Answer (score 2):

First, you must learn that 15:00 is not an int.

Use `NSDate`, not `NSNumber`

Answer (score -1):

You can display four times in table.

[image: ss]

The code is below:

```
array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDate *date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *s = @"HH:mm";
dateFormatter.dateFormat = s;

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"15:00"];
[array addObject:date];

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"20:05"];
[array addObject:date];

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1:20"];
[array addObject:date];

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3:40"];
[array addObject:date];
```

To compare dates, you can use campare method of NSDate class.

```
NSComparisonResult result = [dt1 compare:dt];
switch(result)
{
case NSOrderedAscending:
    // dt is bigger than dt1
    break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
    // dt is smaller than dt1
    break;
case NSOrderedSame:
    // dt is same with dt1
    break;
}
```

You can download the project from GitHub and just run it.

https://github.com/weed/p120812_NSDateSumple

Comment: Ok, thank you. But how can NSLog show me which time (@"15:00"; @"20:05"; @"1:20"; @"3:40";) is Greater than My Current. I need NSLog to show me JUST FIRST CLOSEST GREATER than my Current time. Thanks